# How to prevent firebase database deactivation when using dynamic links only

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links

Today I was given the warning that my firebase database is going to be deleted in 14 days with the text "Your Security Rules allow anyone on the internet to read or write to your database....Your database has not received traffic for almost 6 months and has insecure rules"

The thing is, I'm not using the storage portion of my firebase database, I'm using only the dynamic links because I like the indirection of static link addresses.

My rules did read:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

... and so I changed them to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

... but I don't think that will have any effect because already "write" was "false" and the message said anyone could write.

And then I went into authentication and enabled email/password (before, nothing was enabled). I have no authorized users.

Is there anything more or different I should do so that the database does not become deactivated? I have created dozens of dynamic links.

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deactivation of the Realtime Database has nothing to do with your usage of Dynamic Links. If all you use is dynamic links, then you won't be affected by the change - and can safely ignore it.